# How do I activate a while() statement with a button C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am making a simple macro clicker with C++. I have a simple program so far.  All it has it 2 buttons, which say "Activate" and "Deactivate" respectively:

[image]
<sub>(source: [000webhostapp.com](https://randomcounternet.000webhostapp.com/pastebasket/macro%20clicker%20GUI.png))</sub>

The main part of my program is the `switch(messages)` function:

```
bool i = false;

switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("button"),TEXT("Activate"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            25,
            30,
            100,
            50,
            hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL
            );
        CreateWindow(
            TEXT("button"),TEXT("Deactivate"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            150,
            30,
            100,
            50,
            hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL
            );
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1){
            i = true;
            while(i == true)
            {
                if(GetKeyState(0x43) & 0x8000)
                {
                    usleep(13625);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        if(LOWORD(wParam) == 2){
            i = false;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The `while(i == true)` loop is the clicking loop that gets activated when the "Activate" button is pressed.  The loop checks if the `C` key is held, and if true, it will click really, really fast. This, for some reason, crashes whenever the "Activate" button is pressed.

I have a working Macro Clicker, but I am unhappy with it because it uses the command prompt window and `cout << "Clicking Queued";` as an interface.

If anyone can tell me what is wrong and how to fix it, it will be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: "This, for some reason, crashes" What's the crash?

Comment: Also, once the loop starts, it won't ever stop, because you only have one thread, and that thread is busy in the loop. You won't even be able to move the window properly, much less click on it.

Comment: The crash is just a `(not responding)` crash.  I don't really know how else to explain it other than that.  And even when I click "Activate", the loop does not start, I can't click really fast like on my working program.  All I'm looking for is a way to get around doing what I want to do.

Comment: I know why it has "(not responding)", but that's not a crash. That's a freeze.
I'll give you a hint: When you click "Activate", the loop _does_ start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running an endless loop that blocks the app's UI message loop from processing new messages, thus preventing the "Deactivate" button from being clickable, and preventing `GetKeyState()` from updating the calling thread's local key state information.  The app is not crashing, it is simply not responding to the OS.

**NEVER block a UI thread from processing messages.**

This code needs to be re-written.

When the "Activate" button is clicked (or when you receive a `WM_KEYDOWN` message for the `C` key), start a timer or worker thread instead, and then exit back to the UI message loop.  Let the timer/thread submit the mouse events as needed (and you should be using `SendInput()` instead of `mouse_event()` for that).

When the "Deactivate" button is clicked (or when you receive a `WM_KEYUP` message for the `C` key), stop the timer/thread.

For example:

```
LRESULT WINAPI MyWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow(
                TEXT("button"),TEXT("Activate"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                25,
                30,
                100,
                50,
                hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL
            );

            CreateWindow(
                TEXT("button"),TEXT("Deactivate"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                150,
                30,
                100,
                50,
                hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL
            );

            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 1:
                    SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 13, NULL);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_TIMER:
            if (GetKeyState(0x43) & 0x8000)
            {
                /*
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                */

                INPUT inputs[2] = {0};

                inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

                inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

                SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I had to change `input[0]` to `inputs[0]`, there was a compiling error.

Comment: @user3470353: fixed